Alien invasion where the aliens don't blink
It is a movie made after 2000 about alien invasions. The invaders appear human but later some people discovered by staring at a female through a recorded footage that they DO NOT BLINK. (NOT The Invasion from 2007.) At the start the invaders all wear sunglasses. In the middle of the movie, two invaders were in a room, one standing up, one sitting down. The one who was sitting, shoots the other one and takes off his glasses and says he likes his appearance and that he's the new leader of the invasion. Near the end of the movie it has a scene where all the major cities of the world are covered, like Shanghai, Tokyo, London etc. And at the VERY end, the climatic part, the main protagonist deflects tons of gun fires with one arm like a force field.
What movie is this? I remember the protagonist's face a tiny bit which I THINK is Neo from "The Matrix" so the movie may be one of its sequels (2003) but I haven't watched any of the two movies (technically speaking).

Is Godzilla there? (I'm serious.)

Not necessarily Godzilla, but thank you for mentioning it because I recall there WAS some kind of giant Monster on the invader's side I think. Any ideas?

Yeah, and too many things fit for this not to be it. ;) I'll put it up.

All these things can be found in Godzilla: Final Wars from 2004:

Human-looking aliens that wear sunglasses (seen here) and never blink
A protagonist (seen here) that slightly looks like Keanu Reeves
A scene where a person is found to be an alien when people go over some footage and find out that they don't blink
A scene (seen here) where alien monsters invade many cities around the world
A late scene where the protagonist deflects lots of fire-power with his hand, Matrix-style (seen here)

Among it all, though, there's also Godzilla and Rodan other monsters duking it out. Here's the trailer:




No problem. :) A lot of stuff in this film is, er, 'influenced' by The Matrix.
